# Multiple calls to WebGL drawElements result in incorrect rendering

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl

My Question is: Why does the same example WebGL code result in different output on different platforms/browsers?

In Firefox 30.0 (and the latest one, 32) on Windows, but not on Mac, making multiple drawElements calls results in incorrect rendering when rendering points:[image]

Above Left: Firefox (incorrect).
Above Right: Chrome (correct).

I've re-created this issue (first encountered in a software project which I cannot share) by copying and adapting the sample code from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/webgl/sample5/index.html

I then modified the sample code for maximum simplicity, removing all animation, and rendering three points instead of a cube, with three calls to drawElements, changing color with a uniform for each.

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesIndexBuffer);
  setMatrixUniforms();
  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLoc,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  /*****
  gl.drawElements(gl.POINTS, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); //commented out, from original example.
  *****/
  gl.drawElements(gl.POINTS, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLoc,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
  gl.drawElements(gl.POINTS, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 2);
  gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLoc,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
  gl.drawElements(gl.POINTS, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 4);
```

The three points rendered are supposed to be in a straight line:

```
var vertices = [
// Front face
-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
-1.5, -1.0,  1.0,
-2.0, -1.0,  1.0, //more verts not shown...
```

I've shared the complete source via a public google-drive folder for anyone who feels like being extremely helpful:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5OXnggcG9_7VlZHY003UzFYNGc&usp=sharing

Sadly, Firefox 30 is the platform used (non-negotiable) by our client, so no easy fix by changing browsers.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This seems to be a bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1081376). I'd guess there is no easy workaround except not to use offsets in `gl.drawElements` when using Firefox. :(  It's possible the issue is only with `POINTS` so you could draw points using quads instead as another solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and thanks for reporting the bug! I couldn't find anything that looked similar when I searched bugzilla earlier. I'll talk to our client about upgrading to FF33+, or proceed with my workaround, which will probably be something like using multiple vertex buffers, sorted so that I can call drawArrays instead of drawElements.